# After table Partition Select query performance get slow

Tags: performance, postgresql, select, partitioning

I am using `Postgresql 9.1` and I have a table consisting of 36 column and almost 10 cr. 50 lacks record with `date time stamp` On this Table we have one composite `primary key (DEVICE ID TEXT AND DT_DATETIME timestamp without time zone)` 
Now to get query performance we have `partition` the `table day wise` based on the `DT_DATETIME` Fild. Now After `partition` I see that the `query` data retrieval time takes more that the `unpartition` table. I have `on` the parameter called `constraint_exclusion` in `config` file.

Please any solution for the same.

Let me explain Little farther 
I have 45 days GPS data in a table of size 40 GB. Every second We insert min 27 new records(2.5 million record in a day). To keep the table size at steady 45 days we delete 45th days data every night. Now This poses problem in vacuum on this table due to lock.If we have partition table we can simply drop the 45th days child table. 
so by partitioning we wanted to increase query performance as well as solve locking problem. We have tried pg_repack but Twice the system load factor increased to 21 and we had to reboot the server.
Ours is a 24x7 system so there is no down time.

Comment: Partitioning does not generally increase query performance but it decreases it. Partitioning is made for other things like rotating data in and out.

Comment: I did not get you @usr will you be able to send me some link on the same.

Comment: What exactly did you not understand? Partitioning makes query slower most of the time. This is not a performance feature so don't expect performance increase.

Comment: So Will give me some Idea On the above situation how could make my query retrieval Faster. Because I have seen may people recommend the partition to increase the query performance. Like http://www.slideshare.net/Sperasoft/postgresql-perfomance-tables-partitioning-vs-aggregated-data-tables this one

Comment: What does this mean "almost 10 cr. 50 lacks record with date time stamp"? And I don't think that combination of your primary keys a happy solution for searching.

Comment: That means the table consist of 105 million record where every record have a time stamp of its insertion.

Comment: @usr - Partitioning may or may not improve performance. The parameter constraint_exclusion is provided to help the planner avoid scanning some of the partitions. I am not sure why you said partitioning will not improve performance. We must use the column on which partitioning is done, in there WHERE clause.

Comment: @smn_onrocks - Try pasting your explain analyze at http://explain.depesz.com/ and share the link.

Comment: @Jayadevan please look at the link as suggested  http://explain.depesz.com/s/aFo

Comment: @Jayadevan In case you filter on the partition column you merely restore performance to the old level before partitioning. B-trees are very flat and the upper levels are cached. It does not help throughput to split a single tree into multiple smaller trees (like partitioning does it). There are of course rare cases where the query plan with partitioning has much better characteristics. In general, a single well-chosen index is superior.

Comment: Please provide the query you are executing.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from syn_gps_final where s_asset_id ='MH04FJ3892' and dt_message between cast('01/11/2014 00:00:00' as timestamp without time zone) and cast('09/11/2014 23:59:59' as timestamp without time zone);`

Comment: @Jayadevan please look at the link as suggested http://explain.depesz.com/s/lObo

Comment: @smn_onrocks - It is taking about 105 milliseconds, right? How much time was it taking earlier?

Comment: no @Jayadevan it 254.397 ms while priviously it takes 80.25 ms to max 95.50ms

Comment: @smn_onrocks - "actual time=2.162..105.330", right?

Comment: Yes @Jayadevan it is

Comment: I guess earlier the query was accessing the index (PK) once and that was quicker, as @usr suggested? I don't see anything wrong with the plan as it is getting executed now (there is a difference in the estimated rows and actual, but I doubt if that is a big problem). May be someone else can help.

Comment: @Jayadevan Thanks For your help but could you suggest me any thing else for the above scenario. Please suggest me what can I do to change the Query retrieval time reduce if you wish I can send the detail table structure.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an explain analyze result from a case where you did not have the table partitioned, for comparison?

Comment: @smn_onrocks - I do feel that the response time is reasonable. Do you have a specific target that you wanted to achieve? Are you trying  to figure out why partitioning led to a small drop in performance or are you trying to make the query come back quickly? If your objective is to make the query come back quickly, my question would be - do you need all the 36 columns or you can limit to a few columns? I am thinking about index only scans. But a fat index is likely to slow down your writes.

Comment: @Jayadevan I have to keep all The 36 Column in my table as it is a kind of transaction log table, and My basic moto is Query retrieval faster.

Comment: @harmic I really don't understand what you want to know. Will you give me some brief.

Comment: I want to compare the query plans before and after you implemented partitioning, to see if there was any other difference, aside from the overhead associated with partitioning

Comment: See this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267347/choosing-the-right-partitioning-rule "Firstly, you say all access will be through the primary key. This means you will gain no performance benefits from partitioning (at least not in normal usage). The index on each partition will be smaller, but PG needs to pick which partition to check first."

Comment: @Jayadevan Thanks for your help But considering my situation the refereed page didn't help me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

try to use `pg_bouncer` for connection management and memory management or increase RAM in your server....

Comment: -1: what possible correlation does that have with OP's question?